# Can install, but can't access, the pwr package in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting access to the pwr. This is on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, 64 bit.

I'm installing pwr via `packages.install('pwr')`, and loading it via `library(pwr)`, both of which appear successful.

Strangely, I never get access to the pwr object in R.

I tried installing it to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library and ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library.

I also tried installing it with R CMD INSTALL pwr.

I have also tried installing it on my mac mini running Leopard but it can't even find the packages object, and CMD INSTALL pwr returns

> invalid package 'pwr'

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not quite right. It is installed as "pwr" and loaded  as such:

```
> install.packages("pwr", depend = TRUE)
trying URL 'http://cran.uk.r-project.org/src/contrib/pwr_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7915 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
....
> require(pwr)
Loading required package: pwr
> help(package = "pwr")
```

The output from the last command there shows that there doesn't appear to be a `power()` in that package. What you've seen is the `power()` function in the stats package, one of the packages that comes with R. Try `?power` and look at the very top of the help page. It states "package:stats".

Furthermore, `packages.install()` is not a function that me R knows about. I think you meant `install.packages()`?

To summarise. Install the packages using this from within R (if you have a net connection):

```
install.packages("pwr")
```

Then load the package:

```
require("pwr")
```

Then you can start using it.